# ng-repeat uknown number of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Okay this seems fairly odd but i am allowing my users to create any number of category / subcategories they want

When i pull the category data out it might look something like this:

[image]

as you can see from the above example the sub categories can have subcategories this list tree could go on forever.

Now trying to make the menu i have a simple list:

```
    <ul class="nav dker">
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
        <a ui-sref="app.ui.jvectormap" href="#/app/ui/jvectormap">
            <span translate="aside.nav.components.ui_kits.VECTOR_MAP" class="ng-scope">Vector Map</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The issue here is that i don't know how many times i have to repeat the subcategories which makes it impossible for me to know when to check for it?

i hope you know where im going with this how can i make a reliable list that follows the array pattern above when i don't know how many levels there are?

Comment: Probably going to need to make a directive that calls itself as much as it needs to to keep generating the lists

Comment: or maybe find the depth by javascript and generate the html to that depth.. but that again leads to directive but not necessarily recursive

Comment: Please give a sample of the output you would like to generate.  I would guess that you will need a collection manipulation library like Ramda, Lodash, or Underscore to get what you want.

Comment: This might be interesting: http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to create a recursive template which will essentially look something like this:

```
<div data-ng-include="'displaySubcategory.html'"></div>
```

where `displaySubcategory.html` contains the `ng-repeat` and a recursive call to itself.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="category in category.subcategories">
    <h1>{{category.name}}</h1>
    <div data-ng-include="'displaySubcategory.html'"></div>
</div>
```

The idea is that everytime you call `ng-repeat` you are creating a scope around the child element, so a call to `{{category}}` will display the lowest level (current child) of the tree/data structure.